# J2ME intermediate certificates

Tags: java-me, certificate

In J2ME when you sign a JAR with a certificate chain that includes an intermediate certificate (such as one from obtained from Verisign), does the device need to have the intermediate certificate installed as well as the root certificate during verification?

I am guessing the answer is no because the intermediate certificates are stored in the JAD file in the MIDlet-n-m properties where m is 2 or greater, and I believe the device references these while verifying. If that is true then J2ME certificates are different from SSL website certificates which require the intermediate certificates be installed in the browser, correct?

Finally if this is all true then couldn't anyone who gets a certificate from Verisign or any other CA with their root certificate on the device just go ahead and sign their friend's certificates and then their friends will be trusted?

Seems like a flaw in the system if this is all true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate one gets from verisign would typically be trusted to sign a MIDlet but not another certificate. Certificates trusted to sign MIDlets usually are not trusted to sign native applications either.

Between this and the (admitedly advanced and not always available) ability to revoke certificates, the system is fairly safe as long as trust is preceded by due diligence (so your Mobile Network Operator doesn't start trusting trojans and such...)

Frankly, it's not like mobile airwaves are inherently secure anyway.